# Por qué dejaron de "servir" las funciones que ocupaba justo cuando solo me faltaban los días? :(

Tags: c

Holaas, tengo este pedazo de una función de mi código, añadí más abajo.

```
for(i = 0; i <= 28; i++){
            if(atoi(diaC) == vectorDia[i]){
                k = 1;
            }
        }
            if(k == 1){
                if(atoi(diaC) >=1 && atoi(diaC) <=9){
                    while("0"[i] != '\0'){
                        diaAdecuado[i] = "0"[i];
                        i++;
                    }
                    while(diaC[j] != '\0'){
                        diaAdecuado[i+j] = diaC[j];
                        j++;
                    }
                    diaAdecuado[i+j] = '\0';
                    printf("El atoi(diaC) es: %i\n", atoi(diaC));
                    strcpy(dia, diaAdecuado); // Aquí actualiza el valor de la variable "dia" en main (caso 1)
                }else{
                    strcpy(diaAdecuado, diaC); // Aquí actualiza el valor de la variable "dia" en main (caso 2)
                    strcpy(dia, diaAdecuado);
                }
                repetir = 0;
            }else{
                system("cls");
                printf("Digite un día válido.\n");
                repetir = 1;
            }
```

Mi situación es que en el "caso 1" no sirven las condiciones que le puse, según yo era para saber si el día que digitase el usuario fuera de un solo dígito y entonces debía agregarle un "0" a la izquierda con esos ciclos while que se ven ahí, (la función 'diaC' si la tengo declarada como string).

Imprimí el "atoi(diaC)" y si imprime lo que es, es en la parte en en la que concateno un "0" y la string "diaC" en diaAdecuado en la que ya no sirve, pues al imprimir "diaAdecuado" no sale nada a pesar de que yo sí le estoy asisgnando un valor ahí.

**La del "caso 2" sí sirve, ese es para los números de dos digitos, y esa si hace lo que debe.**
Edito*: El principio de mi código es este

```
void fechaNacimiento(char *annio, char *mes,char *dia){

// Vectores en donde búscara si los datos ingresados son válidos.
int vectorAnnio[9][10] = {{2022,2021,2020,2019,2018,2017,2016,2015,2014,2013},
                          {2012,2011,2010,2009,2008,2007,2006,2005,2004,2003},
                          {2002,2001,2000,1999,1998,1997,1996,1995,1994,1993},
                          {1992,1991,1990,1989,1988,1987,1986,1985,1984,1983},
                          {1982,1981,1980,1979,1978,1977,1976,1975,1974,1973},
                          {1972,1971,1970,1969,1968,1967,1966,1965,1964,1963},
                          {1962,1961,1960,1959,1958,1957,1956,1955,1954,1953},
                          {1952,1951,1950,1949,1948,1947,1946,1945,1944,1943},
                          {1942,1941,1940,1939,1938,1937,1936,1935,1934,1933}};
int vectorMes[12] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
int vectorDia[31] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31};               
//Año            
char annioC[5], annioAdecuado[3];
//Mes
char mesC[3], mesAdecuado[2];           /*La 'C' es de Comprobación, y Adecuado se refiere a que ahí se va*/
//Día                                   /*a guardar ese dato ya acortado tal cual sale en el CURP original*/
char diaC[3], diaAdecuado[3];
//Iteradores y variable repetir pregunta.
int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, repetir = 0;
```

Realmente lo que hago es guardar el día que ingrese en la variable string "diaC" y mediante **atoi()** es que compruebo que sea un día válido buscándolo en el **vectorDia**, y si es verdadero y el número es uno entre el 1 y el 9, yo no quiero que me regrese eso, por eso los bucles while, para que me regresase "01" o "02" etc... en caso de ser claro, un número de un digito.
En la imagen de abajo muestro como con el mes tengo igual el código, solo que ahí y si funciona y se concatena un "0" a la izquierda siempre que el mes sea entre el 1-9.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: en ese código faltaría el tipo y contenido de las variables y el tamaño de los arrays

Comment: Porfavor añade todo el codigo para que te podamos ayudar @abcLaRry

Comment: ¿Qué es eso de `"0"[i]`? Con eso estás accediendo al caracter i-esimo de la cadena `"0"`, pero ya que esa cadena solo tiene un carácter, solo te va a funcionar si `i=0`, en cuyo caso obtienes el carácter `'0'`. Para i=1 obtendrías el terminador de cadena (caracter `'\0'`) y para cualquier otro valor de `i` la instrucción ya estaría accediendo fuera del string con resultados imprevisibles. No veo qué se pretende con el `while` que usa lo de `"0"[i]` ya que en el mejor de los casos se ejecutaría una sola vez (si i=0) y en el peor daría resultados imprevisibles (si i>1).

Comment: Igual puedes reemplazar todo ese lío por `sprintf(diaAdecuado, "%02d", atoi(diaC))`. Eso toma dia como número y gracias a `"%02d"` lo "imprime" usando dos caracteres, rellenando con 0 por la izquierda si es necesario. Solo que no lo imprime sino que deja el resultado en `diaAdecuado`, porque he usado `sprintf()` en vez de `printf()`. Funciona por tanto para dias de una cifra o de dos cifras. Te evitas también los if.

Comment: sí, lo que hago es concatenar ahí en diaAdecuado, las cadenas "0" y 'diaC', ya que yo no quiero un día con un solo dígito, sino con dos, ahí le añado el cero a la izquierda. Es para luego sacar una curp, y en la curp el dia mes y año si los pone con los respectivos ceros a la izquierda dependiendo el caso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como bien te han dicho en los comentarios, el siguiente código es un sin sentido:

```
"0"[i]
```

Lo que hace ese código es crear un string de longitud 2 (`"0\0"`) y, sobre ese array, recupera la posición `i`. Si `i==0`, entonces devuelve `'0'`, si `i==1`, devolverá `'\0'`, pero si es cualquier otro valor, entonces devolverá lo que se encuentre en una posición de memoria que no pertenece al array, luego su valor será todo un misterio.

Para convertir un número en un string de longitud 2 con 0 a la izquierda puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
char mes[3];
int num_mes = 7;
sprintf(mes, "%02d", num_mes);
```

Comment: Eso lo guarda con ese cero a la izquierda o solo lo imprime así? Gracias por tomarte la paciencia conmigo

Comment: @abcLaRry "eso" genera un string `"07"` y lo almacena en `mes`

Comment: No conocía esa utilidad del printf, voy a investigar sobre eso porque no entiendo muy bien que pasa ahí, y si me reduciría varias líneas, gracias

Comment: @abcLaRry nota que la función no es `printf` sino `sprintf` (tiene una "s" de **stream**) al principio. Es una versión de `printf` que en vez de escribir directamente en `stdout`, lo hace en el array que le pases como primer parámetro